# Batch add tags to posts via phpmyadmin - wordpress

Tags: mysql, wordpress, tags

How would I go about batch assigning tags to posts via phpmyadmin? I have a custom table in my database that contains the postID and one column with a **comma separated list of keywords** for each post/record. I want to use the keyword column as values for my tags for each post.

Is there any way for me to get those tags over to the wp_term_relationships table using an sql query?

Right now I already have each post assigned to one category (and some posts assigned to two categories)...if that makes any difference....I am dealing with almost 200,000 posts.

Thanks for the help!!

Answer (score 1):

I thought I could do this with sql queries but that is just over my head..so I did some extensive searching for plugins (free plugins that is...).

I came up with this, which is working....

Installed the '[WP Post Corrector](http://wordpress.org/extend/plugins/wp-post-corrector/)' plugin, it is old and not updated anymore but it is working with my 3.5.1 wordpress. I have a massive csv file with 2 columns (ID -> which is the same as my wp post ID, and post_tag -> which is a list of comma separated tags). I split the file up into smaller chuncks so php or the server wouldn't crap out (http://sourceforge.net/projects/splitcsv/) - I made each file have 5000 records.

Yes, it took me about an hour to upload about 40 files, but now it is done.